# Accessing C# code from JavaScript/HTML without ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, wcf

I have a WCF service running in Visual Studio. I have a few files that display a web interface for the service in a browser. I also have a setting in Web.config that the user can set to disable/enable the interface. I need my JavaScript to be able to see this setting to disable/enable the interface buttons.

I know this is possible using an aspx page with a code-behind class that accesses the Web.config, but is it possible to access the setting using just HTML/JavaScript, without an aspx page?

Answer (score 0):

you can do ajax call with js to your wcf and get the required settings

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924552(v=vs.110).aspx

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: While this answer may be technically correct, you might want to add some more content to it, including some example-code. Link-only answers are frowned upon, and will tend to get voted down.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you can configure it, you should not allow direct access to web.config from the UI (HTML/JS). This would allow anyone to query configuration (like DB connection strings) by modifying the page and is a security concern. Rather load the settings you are interested in to a web service and allow the HTML/JS to query that. Alternatively, write them in to the page you are rendering as parameters (even hidden text boxes) or use the service side to control the rendering.

If you are trying to run this on a client only (i.e. from a folder and not from a web server), then you will not be able to read files due to security isolation. In this case, controlling the parameters from the url querystring may be a better approach than a web.config.